The drilldown is not working after the first animation
I've created a drilldown chart to transact the graphs. The first configuration (from pie chart to bar chart) works. But from then on I couldn't configure the gaugeOn function to make it work.
Code:


<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.5.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="chart"></div>

<style>
  .chart {
    width: 400px;
    height: 430px;
  }
</style>

<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const chartUse = echarts.init(document.getElementsByClassName("chart")[0])

    function chartSystem() {
      return {
        source: {
          first: [
            ["x", "y", "childs"],
            ["Cars", 49, "cars"],
            ["Bikes", 65, "bikes"],
            ["Engines", 23, "eng"],
          ],
        },
        drill: {
          bar: [
            ["x", "y", "groups", "childs"],
            ["Mazda", 100, "cars", "bra"],
            ["Mass.", 120, "cars", "bra"],
            ["Accura", 150, "cars", "bra"],
            ["Kaw.", 20, "bikes", "arg"],
            ["Honda", 50, "bikes", "arg"],
            ["Yamaha", 80, "bikes", "arg"],
            ["V8", 60, "eng", "ned"],
            ["V10", 120, "eng", "ned"],
            ["V12", 20, "eng", "ned"],
          ],
          gauge: [
            ["name", "value", "groups"],
            ["Joao", 100, "bra"],
            ["Maria", 120, "bra"],
            ["Carlos", 20, "arg"],
            ["Bruna", 50, "arg"],
            ["Fabricio", 120, "ned"],
            ["Giovana", 20, "ned"],
          ],
        },
      }
    }

    let pullDataset = []
    let pullData = []
    let pullDrillBar = []
    let pullDrillGauge = []

    function chartSend() {
      const dfInit = chartSystem()
      const sourceIndex = dfInit.source
      const drillName = dfInit.drill

      pullDataset = [
        {
          source: sourceIndex.first, // Acessa "first"
          sourceHeader: true,
        },
      ]

      // Todos os dados de drill
      pullDrillBar = drillName.bar

      pullDrillGauge = drillName.gauge
    }

    chartSend()

    function chartFrameSwitch0() {
      const series0 = {
        type: "pie",
        color: ["#008cba", "#ff7400", "#00ff00"],
        radius: ["80%", "60%"],
        padAngle: 4,
        animationDurationUpdate: 1000,
        universalTransition: {
          enabled: true,
          divideShape: "split",
        },
        itemStyle: {
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#242832",
        },
        datasetIndex: 0,
        encode: {
          itemName: 0,
          value: 1,
          itemChildGroupId: 2,
        },
      }

      const option = {
        dataset: [pullDataset[0]],
        series: [series0],
      }

      // Define o gráfico inicial
      chartUse.setOption(option, { notMerge: true })
    }

    chartFrameSwitch0()

    // Evento de clique no gráfico de pizza
    function barOn() {
      chartUse.on("click", (params) => {
        if (params.seriesType === "pie") {
          const filtered = pullDrillBar.filter((row) => {
            return row[2] === params.data[2]
          })

          if (filtered.length) {
            const preparedData = [...filtered]
            drillCarrierBar(preparedData) // Gera o gráfico com o cabeçalho incluído
          }
        }
      })
    }

    barOn()

    // Evento de clique no gráfico de gauge
    function gaugeOn() {
      chartUse.on("click", (params) => {
        if (params.seriesType === "bar") {
          // Remove o cabeçalho ao filtrar os dados
          const filtered = pullDrillGauge.filter((row) => {
            return row[2] === params.data[2]
          })

          if (filtered.length) {
            // Prepara os dados para o gráfico gauge
            const prepared = filtered.map((row) => ({
              name: row[0],
              value: row[1],
              groupId: row[2],
            }))

            // Atualiza o gráfico de gauge
            drillCarrierGauge(prepared)

            // Exibe os dados no console para depuração
            console.log(prepared)
          }
        }
      })
    }

    gaugeOn()

    function drillCarrierGauge(data) {
      const series0 = {
        type: "gauge",
        data: [...data],
        universalTransition: {
          enabled: true,
          divideShape: "split",
        },
      }

      const option = {
        series: [series0],
      }

      chartUse.setOption(option, { notMerge: true })
    }

    function drillCarrierBar(data) {
      const xAxis0 = {
        type: "category",
        axisLabel: {
          color: "#000",
          fontSize: 14,
        },
      }
      const yAxis0 = {
        type: "value",
      }

      const series0 = {
        type: "bar",
        datasetIndex: 0,
        encode: {
          x: 0,
          y: 1,
          itemGroupId: 2,
          itemChildGroupId: 3,
        },
        color: ["#008cba", "#ff7400", "#00ff00"],
        animationDurationUpdate: 1000,
        universalTransition: {
          enabled: true,
          divideShape: "split",
        },
      }

      const option = {
        dataset: [
          {
            source: [...data],
            sourceHeader: false,
          },
        ],
        xAxis: [xAxis0],
        yAxis: [yAxis0],
        series: [series0],
      }

      // Atualiza o gráfico com as barras
      chartUse.setOption(option, { notMerge: true })
    }
  })
</script>



I believe that the problem lies in the subsequent clicks, as the console.log(filteredData) in gaugeOn has no effect. The graph does not trigger the click.
I also tried putting barOn and gaugeOn in the same structure (drillChanges):
// drillChanges function
function drillChanges() {
  chartUse.on("click", params => {
  
    if (params.seriesType === "pie") {
    
      const filtered = pullDrillBar.filter(row => {
        return row[2] === params.data[2]
      })
      
      if (filtered.length) {
        drillCarrierBar(filtered)
      }
      
    } else if (params.seriesType === "bar") {
    
      const filtered = pullDrillGauge.filter(row => {
        return row[2] === params.data[2]
      }
    )
    
    if (filtered.length) {
        const prepared = filtered.map(row => ({
          name: row[0],
          value: row[1],
          groupId: row[2],
        }))
        drillCarrierGauge(prepared)
      }
      
    }
    
  })
}

drillChanges();

But it doesn't work either.

You have a minor error in the code for gaugeOn - where filtered is computed, the condition should be row[2] === params.data[3]; it's possible that it's still not working properly, so please elaborate on what's still not OK, if that's the case.

@kikon The transition from one graph to the other works, but now the universalTransition from bar to gauge is not working. The transition occurs abruptly, even if I specify the groupId (in gauge, which doesn't support dataset: [...]). I would like the transition to occur smoothly, as it does from pie to bar (where one sector of the chart turns into three bars).

I used the drillChanges function for the transition. My goal would be for the bar to turn into two pointers, just as a pie chart sector turns into three bars. I removed chartUse.off(“click”) and the universalTransition takes place, but notice that it doesn't transform from one bar to two pointers, but rather an independent transition, which seems to start from point 0 of the gauge.

The transition effect I want to execute is something like this:
if (filtered.length) {             const prepared = filtered.slice(1).map(row => ({               name: row[0],               value: row[1],               groupId: row[2]             }))             drillCarrierGauge(prepared)           }
With slice(1) it filters the first one, but my intention here is only to show the transition effect that should occur. See that the bars have turned into a single pointer.

I saw that it works if there's only one data point in the gauge, it can't handle multiple data points, so then how about putting each data point into its own series for the gauge, like in this fiddle?

But it still applies the smoothed transition to only one item. The others start from point 0 and stop at their target value. I've tried to solve it but unfortunately I can't.

1/4 My conclusion, after some serious debugging into the code of echarts is that this kind of many-to-many transitions don't work, i.e., they don't create morph animation; (reference in the source code universalTransition.ts#L492 and the lines above). The many-to-many case means that there are more than one source data points (by groupId or childGroupId) in the old serie, and more than one data points in the new serie (that have the same groupId).

2/4 What works is A) one-to-many (one source data point and possible multiple points in the new serie), B) many-to-one (the other way around) or C) multiple one-to-one, where the dataset is the same between the old and new series but something else changes, like the series type.

3/4 This fiddle contains the standard drilldown example from the docs. It is one-to-many for the drilldown and many-to-one for the "back" transition. The same example can be transformed into a many-to-many case, by setting the groupIds of two of the initial data points to the same value, as in this edit of it that has two groupId: 'animals'; now the animal transition doesn't work, while for the cars it works as before.

4/4 It's possible that I missed something. I'd encourage you ask a new question with just this issue, possibly using the code form the last fiddle as a MRE; there are people more knowledgeable than me in the settings of echarts, so maybe we could find out something that I haven't considered.
